# jQuery sends NaN instead of integer in Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-boot, nan

I develop small backend service/application with Spring Boot and some jQuery/AJAX.

Recently while testing admin functionality I faced strange issue related with the code provided below:

```
function updateUserRow(id) {
  $.get(ajaxUrl + id, function (data) {
      $('.userPlaceBtns').empty();
      $('.userArticleBtns').empty();
      $.each(data, function (key, value) {
          form.find("textarea[name='" + key + "']").val(value);
          form.find("input[name='" + key + "']").val(value);
          form.find('input:checkbox').prop(value ? 'checked' : '');
          if(key == 'placeIds' && value.length != 0){
              for(i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                     $('<button/>', {
                        text:  value[i],
                        id: 'btn_place_'+i,
                        click: function () { 
                            inspectOwnedPlace(value[i]); 
                        }
                    }).appendTo('.userPlaceBtns');
                  }
          }
          if(key == 'articleIds' && value.length != 0){
              for(i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                     $('<button/>', {
                        text:  value[i],
                        id: 'btn_article_'+i,
                        click: function () { 
                            inspectOwnedArticle(value[i]);
                        }
                    }).appendTo('.userArticleBtns');
                  }
          }
      });
      $('.load-bar').hide();
      $('#userEditRow').modal();
  });
}
```

So, besides modal forms data filling, this function helps me to iterate through user-related data and place a button on prepared `div`s for each of this data.

Strange things happen when I try to inspect user-related places or articles with `$.get` from server:

```
function inspectOwnedPlace(id){
    console.log(id);
    var intId = parseInt(id);
    console.log(placesAjaxUrl + intId);
    $.get(placesAjaxUrl + intId, function (data) {
          var placeForm = $(".ownedPlaceForm");
          $.each(data, function (key, value) {
              placeForm.find("textarea[name='" + key + "']").val(value);
              placeForm.find("input[name='" + key + "']").val(value);
          });
          $('#inspectOwnedPlaceModal').modal();
      });
}
```

---

### The Issue

For some reason, in **50-70%** of cases I get `NumberFormatException` on server side because of `NaN` incoming with server request. But in **SOME** cases it definitely works as expected!

Important thing is: the text on generated buttons **ALWAYS** appears as expected, so I can make conclusion that server always gives relevant, 
non-spoiled data to the front and something in JS code leads to frequent `NaN` exceptions when I try to request user-relevant data by id as the next step.

Here is a screenshot of the case when I face this issue (browser tab with dev console) for better understanding:

[image]

So, here I get server's `NumberFormatException` because of `NaN` instead of integer.

**What I tried:**

- treat ids as they are by default not usig `parseInt()` function;
- treat ids as strings and parse them as text.

I just wonder what can lead to non-predictable, non-systemic `NaN`s, which are more likely "spoiled integers", in the context of my current code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can create screenshots of the problem, then I’m assuming you can at least reproduce it reliably enough, that you should be able to step through the whole thing in the debugger, and find out where exactly it goes wrong, no?

Comment: The `NaN` comes when you execute `parseInt(undefined)`. Another good practice is to set the [`radix`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Parameters) parameter at `parseInt`.

Try debugging the `click` handlers and the `for` loops where you are creating the buttons.

Comment: The only place where you seem to be calling the function in question is `inspectOwnedPlace(value[i])`, and there you are passing a value from your JSON data into the function directly, so the buttons etc. seem highly irrelevant (because whatever you do with them, how you place the value on them, maybe format it, doesn’t matter, since it is never actually read back _from_ the button) - which leaves only the suspicion that your AJAX data is messed up to begin with …

Comment: Why you are trying to parse those values as integers in the first place, is still the question. That would only make sense if what you get via AJAX are not actual numbers, or at least correct numeric notations in string form, to begin with. You are putting it into a URL afterwards, so the context becomes string again … which makes me doubt whether your little “excursion” into the world of integer makes _any_ sense here to begin with …?

Comment: @CBroe, fair enough, I'm not JS type of guy so the first thing I doubt is provided JS code. I tried to fit backend controller methods for `string` values as well as to not format data in JS code, but had the same result. Seems that AJAX data is messed for now.